# Conversion unix timestamp attribute to normal date

Tags: apache, unix, timestamp, apache-nifi

I've problem with conversion unix timestamp attribute in my Apache Nifi Template.

**FlowFile**: the ListenTCP component listens to incoming Squid logs. The UpdateAttribute component then assigns the appropriate schema.name to the appropriate schema. Subsequently the ConvertRecord component, converts files from the format to csv (in the component *GrokReader/RecordWriter/CSVRecordSetWriter* I have completed the Timestamp Format line with the format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss). Finally, the PutFile component writes the output files to the disk.

[My Apache Nifi Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzhku.png)

Based on this solution: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/131320/using-partitionrecord-grokreaderjsonwriter-to-pars.html

This is how the log sent by Squid looks like using a proxy:

```
1518442283.483     161 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 103701 GET http://www.cnn.com/ matt DIRECT/199.27.79.73 text/html
```

This is Grok Expression (in **GrokReader**):

```
%{NUMBER:timestamp}\s+%{NUMBER:duration}\s%{IP:client_address}\s%{WORD:cache_result}/%{POSINT:status_code}\s%{NUMBER:bytes}\s%{WORD:request_method}\s%{NOTSPACE:url}\s(%{NOTSPACE:user}|-)\s%{WORD:hierarchy_code}/%{IPORHOST:server}\s%{NOTSPACE:content_type}
```

This is schema.name = nifi_logs (in **AvroSchemaRegistry**):

```
    {
"type": "record",
"name": "nifi_logs",
"fields": [
   { "name": "timestamp", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "duration", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "client_address", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "cache_result", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "status_code", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "bytes", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "request_method", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "url", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "user", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "hierarchy_code", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "server", "type": "string" },
   { "name": "content_type", "type": "string" }
  ]
}
```

At the output of the program I get a file in which the column fomat should have the format for example **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss**:

```
timestamp,duration,client_address,cache_result,status_code,bytes,request_method,url,user,hierarchy_code,server,content_type
1518442283.483,161,127.0.0.1,TCP_MISS,200,103701,GET,http://www.cnn.com/,matt,DIRECT,199.27.79.73,text/html
```

I don't know how to do it, despite many attempts, unfortunately it wasn't possible to change the timestamp format.

I tried these solutions:

- http://www.youritgoeslinux.com/impl/bigdata/nifi/apache
- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

In your schema everything is defined as a string, so the readers and writers will never attempt to make use of the Timestamp Format because none of the fields are being interpreted as timestamps.

You could change your schema to make timestamp be an actual timestamp type, or you should be able to use UpdateRecord and add a property like this:

```
/timestamp = ${field.value:format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')}
```

With the Replacement Strategy set to Literal Values, this is basically saying to update the timestamp field in place by converting it from a string to a date and then back to formatted date string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BryanBende. In AvroSchemaRegistry the field named **timestamp** can't take the timestamp type, because it's in UNIX format, so you can save it as string or number/long type. Unfortunately, but adding the line `/ timestamp = $ {field.value: format ('MM / dd / yyyy HH: mm: ss')}` to the UpdateAttribute nothing has changed (link with settings screen https://ufile.io/ccn3d).

Comment: Not UpdateAttribute, but UpdateRecord, and the key needs to be "/timestamp", not "timestamp"

Comment: This may be helpful for examples of UpdateRecord https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Unfortunately, but despite the recommended settings, the data does not want to go further from the UpdateRecord component. The UpdateRecord component is downloaded (READ), but can not be forwarded (WRITE). Under this link I add a screen with a case-by-case explanation: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/77f5d94bc9f2d3c6f7134d089c566ccb20180420102920/4e131b)